# Blazor Server Side + Apache + Azure AD

Tags: apache, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm integrating Azure AD into a server side blazor application. It works locally (using https), however when I deploy it to production, the redirect URI in the URL is HTTP, not HTTPS, which then once I log in, Microsoft say the redirect URI isn't valid.

I'm running a VM using Ubuntu and Apache, which is forwarding anything from port 80 to port 443 using a Lets Encrypt certificate, however when it sends the user to Microsoft to login, the redirect URI is http://mydomain.tld, rather than https://mydomain.tld. I think it's because the URL it's running on locally is http://localhost:9000 - But when I put it to https://localhost:9000, it throws an exception on start up as it doesn't have a certificate and as I'm not running on a development machine, I don't really want to install the net core SDK and create dev certificate.

I've seen a few people put this in their code to solve it, however my requests are still going through to Azure AD with a HTTP redirect URI:

```
 var fordwardedHeaderOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions     
{         
ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto     
};     
fordwardedHeaderOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();     
fordwardedHeaderOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();      
app.UseForwardedHeaders(fordwardedHeaderOptions);
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? I can't imagine I'm the first to be using Blazor behind Apache and connecting via openid.

Comment: I'm not sure about the complications added by Apache and port forwarding, but from an [AzureAD perspective](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url) they say *The redirect URI must begin with the scheme https. There are some exceptions for localhost redirect URIs.*... so you will need an `https`when you go to use it with your `mydomain.tld`. That's at least one of your problems.

Comment: For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: Yeah - I think the problem is because locally (on the production server), it's running under http, with a proxy from apache redirecting traffic from https to the kestrel server. If I run the kestrel server as https, it exceptions as there's no certificate to bind to. I think I just need to bind to a SSL certificate in production.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1.Set up Redirect URIs: `http://localhost/****`

2.Edit the Manifest like below:
[image]